# How to write a pattern that matches all linear combinations of functions involved except 0?

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to write the simplest (and efficient) pattern that matches the linear combination of all functions except when the combination produces zero?

Consider the following as an example:

```
pattern=HoldPattern[Except[0,(_:1)*Optional[Fibonacci[_],0]+(_:1)*Optional[LucasL[_],0]]];
```

Now if I use this to match the following cases:

```
MatchQ[pattern]/@{
    0,
    2 LucasL[n],
    Fibonacci[n],
    -(Fibonacci[n]/2)+LucasL[n]/2
}
```

I want the pattern to produce true for the last three, i.e. `{False, True, True, True}`.

How do I fix this `pattern`?

Answer (score 3):

There is no [`Optional`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) specification that I know of.  In the OP `pattern` the [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html) head is specified in the pattern so cases of individual terms are not matched.

I use [`Alternatives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) to construct a pattern for the terms, `termPattern`.  Then use `Alternatives` with [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) to allow for an individual term or a linear combination of the terms.

With

```
termPattern = (_ : 1) Optional[Fibonacci[_] | LucasL[_], 0];
pattern = Except[0, termPattern | HoldPattern[Plus][termPattern ..]];
```

Then

```
MatchQ[pattern]/@{
    0,
    2 LucasL[n],
    Fibonacci[n],
    -(Fibonacci[n]/2) + LucasL[n]/2
}
```

> ```
> {False, True, True, True}
> ```

Also

```
MatchQ[pattern][
 a LucasL[n] + b Fibonacci[n] - (Fibonacci[n]/2) + LucasL[n]/2
 ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Hope this helps.